# Avoiding nested layouts when using a single onClickListener for an item in ListView

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

The premise is quite simple. I have a list of items, and each item has a `TextView` containing the title of the item, and a `Switch` showing whether the item is on or off. Instead of tapping on the `Switch` to toggle the item being on or off, I want to be able to click anywhere on the item to toggle it. Basically:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:onClick="toggleSwitch">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

However, this will create a nested layout when used in a screen, which might be bad for performance. I was wondering, since this `ConstraintLayout` is literally just a container with an `onClick`, whether there was a way to implement this layout in a way which avoids nested layouts. Thanks!

Comment: From your question, what i understand is you want to place those two UI-controls side by side instead of overlapping one on top of another in that ConstraintLayout. Am i right?

Comment: Not quite, I want to create an onClickListener (that toggles the Switch) which is triggered if you click anywhere on that item row. As opposed to only being able to click on the Switch to toggle it. And I was wondering whether there is a way to do this without using a "container" layout to encompass the entire row.

Comment: As per my knowledge, there is no other way to achieve your desired functionality without a container. Yes, of course, there is the way where you can provide a same toggleSwitch method in onClick of all UI-Controls in your row layout, but it'll become as a headache when you have so many widgets in your single row-item.

Answer (score 0):

You can just give your textView and your button the same method that will be called on click, that way on every view click (anywhere on the item) you will call your method.

**For example:**

```
   textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //change you switch state
        }
    });

   switch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             //change you switch state
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, the problem with this is that I also want to be able to click on any whitespace inside the item row and toggle the switch. This way, I could only click inside the TextView or on the Switch, not anywhere in between. But my question might not have indicated that, so I've edited it to be clearer.

Comment: So just add another click listener on your ConstraintLayout, that should solve this

Comment: In the example above, my ConstraintLayout already has an onClickListener and that would work, but my question is whether it's possible to encompass the entire row with an onClickListener without using a container layout like above, to avoid having nested layouts.

Comment: I don't think that this option exists, even if you will use groups you cant perform single clickListner for the entire inner group's views.